# CSS3 Transition (zoom) an image that is defined with %s

Tags: css

Say I have the following code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V99bT/)):

**CSS**

```
.holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 475px;
    height: 360px;
}
.zoooom {
    width: 475px;
    height: 360px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.zoooom:hover {
    width: 575px;
    height: 460px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">
    <img class="zoooom" src="../example_image.png" />
</div>
```

The image zooms nicely. However, this is no use with a responsive, %-based layout as the containing `<div>` stretches to fit the zoomed-in image. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V99bT/1/))

Is there any way this can be rectified?

**Live Example**

See the image grid on http://www.matthewpeckham.com/vivid-exposure/ for a better understanding of what I would like. This page is Bootstrapped, and the images need to stay within the confines of the `col-xs-2` `div`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive home-image" src="images/<?=$filename?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive home-image" src="images/<?=$filename?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive home-image" src="images/<?=$filename?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive home-image" src="images/<?=$filename?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive home-image" src="images/<?=$filename?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive home-image" src="images/<?=$filename?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.home-image {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.home-image:hover {
    max-width: 120% !important;
}
```

Comment: Would `transform:scale` be a better option?

Comment: Set the height of the .holder to a fixed pixel amount, like 300px and leave the image in percentages.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of this technique? I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep outer holder fixed.

```
  .holder {
overflow: hidden;
width: 238px;
height: 180px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}

.zoooom {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
transition: all 1s ease;}

.zoooom:hover {
width: 120%;
height: 120%;}
```

Incase outer container is in percentage try webkit scale:

```
.holder {
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 50%;
}
.zoooom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.zoooom:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers !!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong problem is image is not zooming or you want it to centralize in same div ?

Comment: I don't mind how or where it zooms (for now), all I want is the containing `div` to stay at it's current size (e.g. 50%) and the image zoom within it.

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to keep the `.holder { width: ... }` as a  fixed value - it's a percentile-based layout, and must be equal to 1/6 of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/4K49A/)

Fully responsive (honors the bootstrap grid classes) and doesn't require you to set any fixed height or width values on your grid elements.

**CSS:**

```
/*Remove the padding from the cols so there are no gaps in the "portfolio"*/
.portfolio [class^="col"] {
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
.inside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row portfolio">       
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/350" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/360/360" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/370/370" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/380/380" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/390/390" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="inside">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/410/410" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How it works:**
Much like the responsive embed classes in Bootstrap, this uses an intrinsic ratio to maintain the 1:1 ratio of the container using a wrapper and inside class.  The wrapper class has its height expressly set to 0 and padding-bottom set to 100%.  The inside class then uses absolute positioning so it is unaffected by its parent having 0 height, yet percentages can be applied to its height because of the parent not only has an express height value but it also has calculable height due to the padding-bottom property being set to 100%.

With the overflow property set to hidden on the inside class, you can use scale to transform your image on hover.